# How to add Pagination Ellipsis dynamically using react bootstrap pagination.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, react-bootstrap, react-pagination

I have an API items which is working fine including the `Pagination.First, Pagination.Prev, Pagination.Item, Pagination.Next and Pagination.Last`.

I want to add the `Pagination.Ellipsis` on it but I don't have any idea how to insert it to my code.

See docs for pagination [react-bootstrap.github.io](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/pagination/)

Here is the example of what I'm trying to achieve using pagination ellipses [sandboxEllipses](https://r6mg5o.csb.app/).

Below is my code and also here is the sandbox code [https://codesandbox.io/](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-ellipsis-on-react-bootstrap-forked-0qmfvi).

**Movielist.js**

```js
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Col, Card, Row, Pagination } from "react-bootstrap";
import MovieListPagination from "./MovieListPagination";

const MovieList = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  // Default current pages and posts
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [postsPerPage] = useState(4);
  // Get current posts
  const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
  const currentPosts = items.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);
  // Change page
  const paginate = (pageNumber) => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
          //console.log(result.results);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      );
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return <div className="p-3">Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div className="p-3">Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <Row className="justify-content-center">
          {currentPosts.map((item) => (
            <Col sm={6} lg={4} xl={3} className="py-3" key={item.id}>
              <Card bg="dark" text="light" className="text-center h-100">
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>{item.title}</Card.Title>
                  <Card.Text>{item.body}</Card.Text>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          ))}
          <Pagination className="justify-content-center">
            <MovieListPagination
              currentPage={currentPage}
              postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
              totalPosts={items.length}
              paginate={paginate}
            />
          </Pagination>
        </Row>
      </>
    );
  }
};

export default MovieList;
```

**MovielistPagination.js**

```js
import { React } from "react";
import { Pagination } from "react-bootstrap";

const MovieListPagination = ({
  currentPage,
  postsPerPage,
  totalPosts,
  paginate
}) => {
  const pageNumbers = [];
  const pagesCount = Math.ceil(totalPosts / postsPerPage);
  const isCurrentPageFirst = currentPage === 1;
  const isCurrentPageLast = currentPage === pagesCount;
  for (let i = 1; i <= pagesCount; i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Pagination.First onClick={() => paginate(1)} />
      <Pagination.Prev
        onClick={() => paginate(currentPage - 1)}
        disabled={isCurrentPageFirst}
      />
      {pageNumbers.map((number) => (
        <Pagination.Item
          key={number}
          className={`${currentPage === number ? "active" : ""}`}
          onClick={() => {
            paginate(number);
          }}
        >
          {number}
        </Pagination.Item>
      ))}
      <Pagination.Next
        onClick={() => paginate(currentPage + 1)}
        disabled={isCurrentPageLast}
      />
      <Pagination.Last onClick={() => paginate(pagesCount)} />
    </>
  );
};

export default MovieListPagination;
```

I tried some work around like `<Pagination.Ellipsis key={pageNumbers} className="muted" />` and the ff code...But It's not working.

```js
  // Add ellipses if there are more pages to display
  if (pageNumbers[0] > 1) {
    pageNumbers.unshift(<Pagination.Ellipsis key="ellipsis-start" />);
  }
  if (pageNumbers[pageNumbers.length - 1] < totalPosts) {
    pageNumbers.push(<Pagination.Ellipsis key="ellipsis-end" />);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For now my answer for my question is using react-paginate. You can find my forked answer here on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-ellipsis-on-react-bootstrap-update-slwwvc).

I will keep my question open, maybe someone might help up. Thx!